# How does Task.CompletedTask work with thread pool?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C# asynchronous programming, just a question on the relationship between task and thread pool.

My understanding is:
When we create a `Task`, this `Task` is queued in the thread pool and the thread pool will schedule a worker thread to run this `Task`

And I saw the code below:

```
public Task InputOutputC() {
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I don't quite get it, it seems that return a `Task` has already completed, which means a worker thread has already run this `Task`, but the meaning of `Task` is to let a worker thread in the thread pool to run it, if it has already finished, what's the point to return it to thread pool again and get executed again?

Comment: "When we create a Task, this Task is queued in the thread pool and the thread pool will schedule a worker thread to run this Task." That is not correct. The Task runs immediately up until its first suspension point. Perhaps you're confusing it with the Task.Run method, which runs the lambda on the thread pool? Task.CompletedTask returns a task that has already completed; the thread pool is not involved.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for your post but I am still confused. You mentioned that " The Task runs immediately up until its first suspension point." what does it mean and which thread is used to run the task if it is not a worker thread from thread pool?

Comment: @amjad there absolutely nothing special about Task class itself - it is just *a class* similar to  let's say a `string`. The code shown in the post does not even have any asynchronous behavior and is not re-written automatically to be state machine (as there is no `async` nor `await`). It would behave exactly the same as `string Getsome() { return "42";}`. There is some special usage of this class when compiler auto-generates code for `async` methods, but it is not the case here.

Comment: Task is an abstraction - promise of some result. How that result is obtained is not part of the abstraction - it can be separate thread, from thread pool or not, can be IO (then device, such as hard drive, executes operation and provides the result), or any other means like you see here.

Comment: "which thread is used to run the task": the same thread that called the method. Only if the code hits something like `await` or `Task.Yield()` it *may* (!) switch to another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the meaning of Task is to let a worker thread in the thread pool to run it,

Running code on the thread pool is ***one*** way in which `Task`s manifest themselves.

Other ways to create `Task`s are to write `async` methods and to use `Task.CompletedTask`<sup>1</sup> or [`Task.FromResult<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=net-5.0)<sup>2</sup>.

Just because `Task.Run` causes code to run on the thread pool does not mean that these other uses of `Task` must also necessarily involve the thread pool.

For `Task.CompletedTask`, especially, this is "I've already done the work required, but I want to present it to other code as a `Task`. No additional code runs *anywhere*.

We can see in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1645) that this property just returns the task:

```
    /// <summary>A task that's already been completed successfully.</summary>
    private static Task s_completedTask;

    /// <summary>Gets a task that's already been completed successfully.</summary>
    /// <remarks>May not always return the same instance.</remarks>        
    public static Task CompletedTask
    {
        get
        {
            var completedTask = s_completedTask;
            if (completedTask == null)
                s_completedTask = completedTask = new Task(false, (TaskCreationOptions)InternalTaskOptions.DoNotDispose, default(CancellationToken)); // benign initialization ----
            return completedTask;
        }
    }
```

---

<sup>1</sup>As shown in the reference source later though, we often aren't even creating a new `Task` here, just reusing an existing one. But the team have obviously decided to forgo thread-safe initialisation of the property in favour of documenting that they won't guarantee to always return the same `Task`.

<sup>2</sup>These latter two are quite similar, in that they represent "I've already done the work required, now for some reason I need to pass some other code a `Task`"<sup>3</sup>.

<sup>3</sup>Often, and I'm guessing as is the case here, when you're implementing an interface or overriding a base class method that is `Task` returning but your code is fast and synchronous so you have no need to be `async`.